# ios 9 emojis are not displayed on devices having ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, emoji

I am having a problem my application has deployment target iOS 8.0. There is a status field of a user where user can post a status along with Emoji icons. The status of user is stored in a database. Now if a user post a status from a device which is updated to ios 9.2 and then log in from another device whose iOS version is 8.4. What happens is that some of the emojis does not show(those which are not available in iOS 8) and they translate to unknown characters. While if a user is on ios 9 its working fine even if he logged in from different devices. How could I solve this problem.

Comment: Something that you would have to know about Emojis , is that are now a standard , ie to run you should regardless of the environment . I think maybe you have problems with the encoding of the file

Comment: can you elaborate a little more I am sending string using encoding NSUTF8StringEncoding. And when I get the data from server I just put the status field back in a NSString. Its working fine on iOS 9.2

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- fall back to an older unicode version (<6 if I remember correctly) by replacing the 'new' emojis with older ones
- do it the hard way and [replace](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID301) certain unicode characters (the new emojis) in your strings with replacements for apps running

The latter might be hackish but ok if we are talking about just a few characters and not tons of texts.

Comment: you said remove the 'new' emojis with the previous ones. The emojis are there in iOS 9.2 how can I replace them?

Comment: Option 1 was: don't use the new stuff because of older OS' – which is probably not what you want but still a valid option. Sorry for the confusion.